# how to implement "no route found " Mesaage when route is not available on Google Map

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app. I am getting error(My app is crashed) when i find Address  out of country on Google map. The reason behind it direction Route.So I want to display a message when no route found "no route found".Using a following code-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView navList;

GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mFragment;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LatLng latLng;
Marker CurrentMarker, NearbyPlace, FindMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = null


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    findbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findbtn);
    autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editplace);

    autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    setListnerOnWidget();


}
private void setListnerOnWidget() {


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String location = autoCompView.getText().toString();
            if (location != null && !location.equals("")) {
                new GeocoderTask().execute(location);

            }

        }
    };
    findbtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}




 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {


    Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}

private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {
        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){
            Address address =  (Address)addresses.get(i);
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getCountryName());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Find Location");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            FindMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(14).build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            double mLatitude=address.getLatitude();
            double mLongitude=address.getLongitude();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
            sb.append("&radius=4000");
            sb.append("&types=" + "liquor_store");
            sb.append("&sensor=true");
            sb.append("&key=AI*************************");
            Log.d("Map", "<><>api: " + sb.toString());

            //query places with find location
            PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
            placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

            //for direction Route
            LatLng origin = CurrentMarker.getPosition();
            LatLng dest = FindMarker.getPosition();

            String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            downloadTask.execute(url);

        }

    }

}

public StringBuilder sbMethod(Location location) {
    //current location
    double mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double mLongitude =location.getLongitude();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
    sb.append("&radius=4000");
    sb.append("&types=" + "liquor_store");
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyC47V7li_j9_M_HyYEW8D5Z2nyFYX7DkuI");

    Log.d("Map", "<><>api: " + sb.toString());

    return sb;
}

@Override
public void onConnected( Bundle bundle) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        //place marker at current position
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        CurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    //mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
    // mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (CurrentMarker != null){
        CurrentMarker.remove();
    }
    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    CurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Location changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod(location));
    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
    placesTask.execute(sbValue.toString());

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}

private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("result", "<><> result: " + result);
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();
        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    JSONObject jObject;
    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        Place_JSON placeJson = new Place_JSON();

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            places = placeJson.parse(jObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }
    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

        Log.d("Map", "list size: " + list.size());
        // Clears all the existing markers;
        if (!firstRun) {

            mMap.clear();
        }
        firstRun = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");
            Log.d("Map", "place: " + name);
            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            NearbyPlace = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    }
}


public class Place_JSON {

    //Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        JSONArray jPlaces = null;
        try {
            //Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array
            jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
        //where each json object represent a place
        return getPlaces(jPlaces);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {
        int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> place = null;

        //Taking each place, parses and adds to list object
        for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
            try {
                // Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place
                place = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
                placesList.add(place);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return placesList;
    }

    // Parsing the Place JSON object

    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String placeName = "-NA-";
        String vicinity = "-NA-";
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        String reference = "";

        try {
            // Extracting Place name, if available
            if (!jPlace.isNull("name")) {
                placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
            }

            // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
            if (!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")) {
                vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
            }

            latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
            reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

            place.put("place_name", placeName);
            place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
            place.put("lat", latitude);
            place.put("lng", longitude);
            place.put("reference", reference);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return place;
    }
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ParTask parTask = new ParTask();
        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parTask.execute(result);
    }
}

//A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
private class ParTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Find Location");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        FindMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

        System.out.println("URL: "+url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {

        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {

            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
 }
```

DirectionsJSONParser

```
 public class DirectionsJSONParser {

public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return routes;
}


private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }
    return poly;
}
 }
```

Please tell me how to implement message "No Route Found" when no route found Google map

Thanks

Comment: paste your error log here..!!

Comment: its not error.when i remove methods of direction app is working correctly to search out of country.when i use these these method working in current country but not search any location in forigen

Comment: you are saying this **I am getting error(My app is crashed) when i find Address out of country on Google map** if it is crashed i need to see the crash log..!!

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.iqwiner, PID: 22238  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'float com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions.c' on a null object reference at maps.af.Z.<init>(Unknown Source) at maps.af.t.a(Unknown Source)  at vl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:137)
 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387) at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addPolyline(Unknown Source  at

Comment: i am getting this error..please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: please tell me ...

Comment: it's a null pointer your map is null i think

Comment: i m confused plz tell me how to resolve it..